# Extract content from local HTML file with RapidMiner

Tags: html, web-scraping, rapidminer

I’m trying since 5 h to retrieve specific content from a locally saved html document. Mainly I would like to gather the Value “Worldwide” and “3,041,070”.

```html
<div itemprop="url" class="rankingItem-underTitle">
<a class="rankingItem-subTitle is-link" data-analytics-category="Internal Link" data-analytics-label="Global Rank/Worldwide" href="/top-websites" itemprop="significantLink">Worldwide</a></div>
<div class="rankingItem-rank js-editable">
<span class="rankingItem-value js-countable" data-value="3,041,070">#3,041,070</span>
```

I really do not know which operators I must choose to get everything working.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In combination with Regular Expression I made it work.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPN7W.png)

Answer (score 0):

First form the extensions install the text mining models the run this simple example. You will get both values.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><process version="7.3.001">
  <operator activated="true" class="text:extract_information" compatibility="7.3.000" expanded="true" height="68" name="Extract Information" width="90" x="313" y="85">
    <parameter key="query_type" value="Regular Expression"/>
    <list key="string_machting_queries"/>
    <parameter key="attribute_type" value="Nominal"/>
    <list key="regular_expression_queries">
      <parameter key="Type" value="itemprop=&quot;significantLink&quot;&gt;(.*)&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;"/>
      <parameter key="Value" value="&quot;&gt;#(.*)&lt;/span&gt;"/>
    </list>
    <list key="regular_region_queries">
      <parameter key="ValueType" value="itemprop=&quot;significantLink&quot;&gt;.&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;"/>
      <parameter key="Value" value="data-value=&quot;.&quot;&gt;"/>
    </list>
    <list key="xpath_queries"/>
    <list key="namespaces"/>
    <parameter key="ignore_CDATA" value="true"/>
    <parameter key="assume_html" value="true"/>
    <list key="index_queries"/>
    <list key="jsonpath_queries"/>
  </operator>
</process>
```